# iPhone thumbnail tabbed web browser

Tags: iphone, web-browser

Is there an iPhone thumbnail tabbed web browser? Mercury used to have this feature and unfortunately it has been removed from the App Store.

[image]

---

I really don't like this type of tab where you have to click the tab button at the top then you have to scroll through the tabs to close them. When I have multiple tabs open on the same website I am often closing the wrong one.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Safari** actually has this! Well, sort of.

Just pinch out or hit the "two squares" button to view your tabs in a Cover Flow-like view. On the iPad it will be a grid of cards that sometimes stack and sometimes don't. This also works on the Mac as well.